# Using ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick on Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, azure-functions

I am trying to see if my company can use Azure Functions to automate conversions of TIFF files to a number of JPG and PNG formats and sizes. I am using Functions with Node.js, but other languages could be used.

My problem is, that I can't get GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick to work on Functions. I used the normal procedures for installment using *npm install*.

It seems to install ok, and the module also seems to load, but nothing happens when I try to process a file. Nothing, as in no errors either.

> var fs = require('fs'); 
>   var gm = require('gm');
>
> module.exports = function (context, req) {
>       context.log('Start...');
>
> ```
> try {
>     context.log('Looking for GM...');
>     context.log(require.resolve("gm"));
> } catch(e) {
>     console.log("GM is not found");
>     process.exit(e.code);
> }
>
> gm('D:/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTriggerJS1/input/870003-02070-main-nfh.jpg')
>     .resize(240, 240)
>     .noProfile()
>     .write('D:/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTriggerJS1/output/resize.jpg', 
>     function (err) {
>         context.log('TEST');
>         if (!err) {
>             context.log('done');
>         }
>     }
> );
>
> context.done(null, res); };
> ```

I'm not sure that it's even possible, but I haven't found any information that states that it *can't*.

So, can I use ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick or a third image converter in Functions? If yes, is there something special that I need to be aware of when installing?

Is there also a C# solution to this?

Comment: c# version would be preferable if possible

Comment: Cloudinary API could be used for image transformations https://cloudinary.com/cookbook/converting_an_image_format from their page `currently supports the following formats: JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP, TIFF, ICO, PDF, EPS, PSD, SVG, WebP, JXR, and WDP`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web Apps in Azure is a SaaS (Software as a Service).  You deploy your bits to the Azure IIS containers, and Azure do the rest. We don’t get much control.
So we will not have the privilege to install any 3rd party executable file on Azure Functions App (e.g. ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick). If you need to do that, look at Virtual Machines. Another option is using Cloud Services' Web or Worker Role.

Alternatively, there is a good image processing library for Node written entirely in JavaScript, with zero external or native dependencies, Jimp. https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

Example usage:

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

Jimp.read("lenna.png").then(function (lenna) {
    lenna.resize(256, 256)            // resize
         .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
         .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
         .write("lena-small-bw.jpg"); // save
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

There is another node.js library called [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) to achieve your requirement. You may try this way:

First, install the sharp on your local environment, and then deploy your application to Azure with the `node_modules` folder which contains the compiled module. Finally, upgrade the node executable on Azure App Service to 64-bits.

The similar thread you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774852/bcrypt-not-a-valid-win-32-application-on-azure-app-service).

Example usage:

```
var sharp = require("sharp");

sharp(inputBuffer)
  .resize(320, 240)
  .toFile('output.webp', (err, info) => {
      //...
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I also read somewhere that you can't install executables on Azure Functions... but I tried it anyway, and it works! I installed GraphicsMagick in a folder and execute a child process for GraphicsMagick, and it does indeed convert the files I want. Is this a bug, or use as intended? I also looked at Jimp, but it can't convert TIFF's so, that's a deal breaker there, unfortunately.

Comment: Just spent 4 hours trying to get sharp running on Azure Functions :-( Just can't get all the pieces together.

Answer (score 3):

Azure functions can run custom docker images also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image

Not sure which language you are interested in, but you can have a python image with below style Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils  && \
    apt-get install -y imagemagick

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then use the [PythonMagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonMagick) to work with the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use the site extension to make imagemagick work for azure web apps.

You can check the repository for more info: https://github.com/fatihturgut/azure-imagemagick-nodejs

Comment: You still have to install the npm package after doing this of course :-)