# bcrypt not a valid win 32 application on azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, bcrypt, appveyor

In order to do some image processing using the Node library, Sharp, I had to upgrade my node executable on Azure App Service to 64-bits. I did this by downloading the executable manually and then setting its path in `IISNode.yml`.

Unfortunately, when I start the app, it throws the following error:

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

```
\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:256:38)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:256:38)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bookshelf-bcrypt\index.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

I'm building and deploying the application using the Appveyor CI system. Here's my the relevant portion of my `appveyor.yml` file:

```
install:
  - ps: Install-Product node $env:nodejs_version x64
  - SET CL=-DDELAYIMP_INSECURE_WRITABLE_HOOKS
  - npm i --loglevel=warn
  - npm prune --production
  - 7z a api.zip * -x!test -x!db -x!.git -xr!.* -x!README.md -x!nodemon.json -x!appveyor.yml | FIND /V "ing  "
```

You'll see that I'm building using a 64-bit version of Node.

On my Azure app service, I have the platform set to 64-bit.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the platform to 32-bit on Azure
- Blowing away node_modules/ on App Service

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default node.js executation applications on Azure Web Apps are all in 32bit. So it raises your issue. We can use the custom node.js runtime to achieve your requirement. Please try the following steps:

1, Put a 64bit node.exe executation application in your application, e.g.
    in a `runtime` folder.

2, Modify the `iisnode.yml`, set:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime\node.exe"
```

3, Deploy your entire application to Azure Web Apps.

Additionally, you can use the following code to verify that whether the node.js binary is `x64` or not.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    response.write(require('os').arch());
    response.end();

}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Where is iisnode.yml? Does this still apply to the 'beta 2' version of Azure Functions?

Comment: Do I literally just need top copy over `node.exe` and nothing else?

Comment: What About Linux Container ? How to do it for Linux version of app service ?