# Azure NodeJS 'Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.'

Tags: node.js, azure

I am trying to make a NodeJS App service using Azure.  However, it appears the node module -[nodehun](https://github.com/Wulf/nodehun)- I am trying to use is interfering with the compilation process.

See error:

```
\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\nodehun\build\Release\nodehun.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
Wed Sep 20 2017 16:18:27 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

After a bit of searching, this can be caused by a mismatch between 32/64bit architecture of node.exe and the built module.  Although, I'm not sure how to fix this problem within Azure.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you got, it seems that `nodehun` requires 64bit node.js runtime. By default, Azure App Service does not have 64bit node.exe installed. The workaround for what you want to do would be place 64 bit node.exe in `d:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime` and then create a `iisnode.yml` with the following content:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime\node.exe"
```

After that done, don't forget to restart your App Service. More details, please refer to [bcrypt not a valid win 32 application on azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774852/bcrypt-not-a-valid-win-32-application-on-azure-app-service/40779769#40779769).

Comment: iisnode.yml didn't exist so I just created it in the root directory.  Do I need to define it anywhere in a config file?

Comment: I added a 64bit version of node to wwwroot\runtime\ and added the iisnode.yml but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted your app service?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it.  I also added 'console.log(require('os').arch());' before the nodehun require, which turns out to still be 'ia32'.

I got the binary from 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/node-v6.11.3-win-x64.zip'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aaron Chen for pointing me in the right direction.

In the Azure web app, there is a Web.config file.  Within this file there is an iisnode section, which I added the nodeProcessCommandLine to, e.g:

```
<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" nodeProcessCommandLine="D:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime\node.exe"/>
```

This fixes the above error and runs node as 64bit, provided a 64bit version of node is supplied.